# Where to park for a passenger drop-off at London Gatwick?

Tags: automobiles, lgw

I have few family members who will be returning home and their flight will be from London Gatwick. After [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=gatwick+airport+parking), I didn't find anything affordable with respect to parking. Following options popped up

1. [Gatwick airport parking](Http://parking.gatwickairport.com)
2. Looking4.com
3. [Purpleparking](https://www.purpleparking.com/gatwick-airport-parking)

But all the above options provide full day parking and it starts with a minimum of £22 even if a select 2 hour parking.

Where to park on hourly basis (drop off or pick up purposes) at Gatwick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Gatwick North and South terminals have [short stay parking](https://www.gatwickairport.com/parking/car-parking-prices/) on site. Just follow the direction signs.

You can also drop off right outside the terminal for £5 but you must only stay a few minutes, and can't leave the car unattended.

[image]

<sub>Image from Google Street View</sub>

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you happen to know the charges for short stay? Or the best option ? Is it online pre-book or onsite pay-at-the-machine option ?

Comment: The charges are given in the link I included. It also says *We always recommend that you pre-book for the best rates. You can also park for up to two hours for free in our long stay car parks if you're picking up friends or family.* The long stay parks are not as close by. I have †never pre-booked: just turn up and park. Many of the internet posted sites are third-party managed, and mostly intended for air passengers who leave their cars while away. (†except long stay when flying).